# Alternative ways to css transform with percentages to animate dom translation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 14 different objects with different positions on the dom that I want to animate translate. Currently I translate using: `transform: translate(x%, y%)`. With this configuration I have to calculate the translation amount for every object and add a css style. This percentage translation also relative to the objects dimensions so I have to re calculate if I change the object dimensions.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 40%;
  padding-bottom: 40%;
  height: 0;
  background: #cdc;
}

.seats {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.seats .seat {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20%;
  height: 20%;
}

.seat.one {
  bottom: 0%;
  left: 50%;
}

.seat.two {
  bottom: 50%;
  left: 0%;
}

.seat.three {
  bottom: 50%;
  left: 80%;
}

.cards {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.cards .dealer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 90%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class="cards">
    <div class="dealer">
      Dealer
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="seats">
  
  <div class="seat one">
    <div class="hand">
    Hand 1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="seat two">
    <div class="hand">
    Hand 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="seat three">
    <div class="hand">
      Hand 3
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want `Hand 1/2/3` to translate to `Dealer` and also I want to reverse this animation.

Also the translation is not right when I change the size of the container.

Is there a better way to translate dom elements that doesn't require a lot of custom tweaking?

Comment: fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eguneys/j0mnq2e8/1/

Comment: very unclear ! could you explain further.

Comment: I want to translate many dom objects, but don't want to write custom `transform: translate` for each of them. Because I have to tweak it everytime I change something. @ths

Comment: I don't believe you can pull data from one element's style to another directly without using some precompiled variable in something like [Sass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sass_(stylesheet_language))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add a CSS class, and toggle that as needed.

```js
const toggle = document.getElementById('toggle');
const seats = document.querySelectorAll('.seat');

toggle.addEventListener('click', e => {
  seats.forEach(seat => {
    seat.classList.toggle('not-dealt');
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 40vmax;
  padding-bottom: 40vmax;
  height: 0;
  background: #cdc;
}

.seats {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.seat {
  position: absolute;
  background: #d99;
  transition: all 2s;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.one {
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
}

.two {
  top: 50%;
  left: 0%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
}

.three {
  top: 50%;
  left: 100%;
  transform: translate(-100%, -50%);
}

.not-dealt {
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
}

.cards {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.dealer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="cards">
    <div class="dealer">
      Dealer
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="seats">
    <div class="seat one">
      <div class="hand">
        Hand 1
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="seat two">
      <div class="hand">
        Hand 2
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="seat three">
      <div class="hand">
        Hand 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button id="toggle">Toggle Cards</button>
```